# Laravel Passport Auth::user()->token return null while Auth::user is not null

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm trying to output the current user's access token in Laravel. This is my current controller
Class PassportController.php

```
class PassportController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            if (Auth::user() == null) return response(['message' => 'Unauthenticated']);
            return $next($request);
        });
    } 
    public function getToken()
    {
        $token = Auth::user()->token;
        return response($token);
    }
}
```

model Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory; use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; // use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute; use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens; use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasFactory, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    
        
        protected $fillable = ['username', 'password'];
        public function messages()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
        }
    
        public function rooms()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class, 'room_user', 'user_id', 'room_id');
        }
    
        protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'password', 'updated_at', 'rmb_token'];
    }
```

Route

```
  Route::get('/tokens', 'API\PassportController@getToken');
```

I have also made sure to include the Authorization header in my Postman request with the content as Bearer {access_token}. While Auth::user returns a user like expected when I tried Auth::user()->token it gives me

> App\Models\User::token must return a relationship instance

error and when I `dd(Auth::user()->token)` I got it as null. I have also remembered to put in

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

in config/auth.php so I'm not sure what could be causing this. I'm running the latest version of Laravel(laravel 9.45.0).

Comment: Could you please try Auth::user()->token() instead of returning it as an attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Auth::user()** - this is a data object containing information about an authorized user, data about which, in turn, is stored in your database in the users table.

**Tokens in this table are not stored and are not stored! If you use passport, then your tokens are stored in the oauth_access_tokens table.**

Therefore, why did you decide that you should contain an authorization token in the Auth::user() object? Of course, unless you somehow write it there through some kind of crutch, modifying the object. But this is fundamentally wrong!

Your authorization controller should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Requests\LoginRequest;

/**
 * Class LoginController
 * @package App\Controllers\Auth
 */
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param LoginRequest $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function login (LoginRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (\Auth::attempt($credentials) === false) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'errors' => ['message' => __('auth.login_error')],
                'data'   => []
            ], 403);
        }

        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('YOUR Personal Access Token');

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'errors' => [],
            'data' => [
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'token'      => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                'expires_at' => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString(),
                'user'       => $user
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Request class will look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

/**
 * Class LoginRequest
 * @package App\Requests
 */
class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|max:20',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param Validator $validator
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        // remove the redirect for authorization by api
        $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'errors' => $errors,
                'data'   => []
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        );
    }
}
```